# How to translate 动感强？

Tags: meaning

Talking about 滑雪： I think maybe they mean 'nerve-tingling' for '动感强‘ but I am far from certain. 动感强 might mean 'very dynamic'. Skiing down a mountain, you can reach very high speeds, you need fast reactions. Because of the risk involved, it is very thrilling and exciting, aka 'nerve-tingling'.

zdic.net has this for 动感， but this text is talking about skiing, not people：

动感： 形容人活潑熱烈、魅力十足

高山滑雪由于具有惊险、优美、动感强、可参与面广的特点，因此被人们视为滑雪运动的象征，是旅游滑雪的首先。

高山滑雪由于具有惊险、优美、动感强、可参与面广的特点，
High altitude skiing, because there are many different aspects to take part in, is thrilling, graceful, and nerve-tingling （??动感强）,

Sometimes, when I have been stuck for a translation, people have said 'this is not good Chinese.' How about this sentence, is it ok?

Comment: Maybe just energetic, lively or something like that

Answer (score 3):

动感 means 动态感觉 =  'dynamic feel'

Examples:

- 这幅画有强烈的动感- This painting has a strong dynamic feel to it
- 此照片色彩鲜艳, 动感强烈 - His photo has vivid color and strong dynamic feel
- 她一身紧身赛车服, 散发出强烈动感- She in a tight car-racing suit, exudes a strong dynamic feel.

Using 动感强 (dynamic feel is strong)  to describe 'high altitude skiing' is kind of inappropriate.

Skiing is a motion . Saying an actual motion make people feel it is moving is an oxymoron.

It is better to say "高山滑雪由于**动态强**" (Because high altitude skiing is **highly dynamic**)